# VHDL Style Checker / Check Style

Tags: vhdl, hdl, code

Is there a style checker for VHDL?

I found [style guidelines](https://wiki.ntb.ch/infoportal/_media/software:programmierrichtlinien:vhdl_guidelines.pdf), but I didn't find anything like check style.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should search for Sigasi Studio.

Comment: The checker should be you, that is the best part about VHDL, it forces you to check your code because it is strongly typed

Comment: Style involves superimposing organizational format and content constraints on syntactically and semantically correct VHDL. Style constraints can be imposed at data entry using VHDL aware smart editors, by elaborated design hierarchy examination or of course by manual code review. The effort to create tools supporting style checking is generally beyond a reasonable return on investment when enclosing all organizationally imposed peccadilloes while commercial offerings can fall short. The subject could be considered off-topic here as a recommendation question prone to opinion answers.

Comment: Check https://github.com/jeremiah-c-leary/vhdl-style-guide , you can define rules.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you use already installed software text editors for checking your syntax errors. There itself you can correct your typing errors or syntax related issues, data type matchings, signal/variable namings etc. Coz it also provides proper text coloring/highlighting of conditional statements, loops, hierarchy etc. Language templates documentation is also given inside the software application for help.

You can also install latest notepad++ for that matter from [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.4.2.html) for re-editing your source code files (It can be used for almost any coding language, not just VHDL). Sometimes it's easier to go through codes in the notepad++ editor rather than opening it in the heavy software application and also better than a simple text editor.

And concerned to your style guidelines, I think it will automatically come to you as your learnings about VHDL grows.

Comment: Yes you are right. A smarter editor would be the most convenient option.

I am currently working with emacs, which has many of the features that you just described. @Paebbels recommended a really cool editor "Sigasi Studio". Maybe I can get some of those features on emacs as well...